# Handling Results from Computer Vision API

Tags: azure, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, azure-cognitive-services

I am playing around with Azure Cognitive Services Computer Vision API and I am running into issues knowing what to do with the results. The use case is I have an image that is a photo of a calendar of events for a particular month. I am running the image through the Computer Vision API OCR Method

https://eastus2.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56f91f2d778daf23d8ec6739/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fc

And get a JSON which is an object of regions, lines, and words with boundaries for each. I am having a hard time finding a way to "group" these items into the desired format. Here is a sample JSON that is returned for this image

https://drive.google.com/file/d/12dO0vIjGNQ8_nARTQbFHmaLNQNOWBC2x/view?usp=sharing

`{
  "textAngle": 0.0,
  "orientation": "NotDetected",
  "language": "en",
  "regions": [
    {
      "boundingBox": "727,56,1692,119",
      "lines": [
        {
          "boundingBox": "727,56,1692,119",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "727,57,727,118",
              "text": "CHILDREN!S"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "1576,58,583,111",
              "text": "JANUARY"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "2280,56,139,114",
              "text": "20"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "boundingBox": "361,265,159,42",
      "lines": [
        {
          "boundingBox": "361,265,159,42",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "361,265,159,42",
              "text": "Sunday"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "boundingBox": "279,593,298,1261",
      "lines": [
        {
          "boundingBox": "279,593,17,26",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "279,593,17,26",
              "text": "7"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "280,633,203,33",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "280,633,102,33",
              "text": "Library"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "394,634,89,32",
              "text": "Open"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "282,675,124,32",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "282,675,7,26",
              "text": "1"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "307,675,37,26",
              "text": "-5"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "356,681,50,26",
              "text": "pm"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "280,716,252,31",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "280,716,71,25",
              "text": "New"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "360,716,73,25",
              "text": "Year"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "444,716,88,31",
              "text": "Open"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "281,757,96,26",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "281,757,96,26",
              "text": "House"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "280,797,297,27",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "280,797,67,27",
              "text": "Start"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "357,797,55,26",
              "text": "The"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "424,797,71,26",
              "text": "New"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "503,797,74,26",
              "text": "Year"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "281,836,286,34",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "281,837,77,33",
              "text": "Right"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "367,837,25,26",
              "text": "@"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "401,837,51,26",
              "text": "the"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "463,836,104,33",
              "text": "Library"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "281,878,110,32",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "281,878,48,26",
              "text": "1-5"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "341,885,50,25",
              "text": "pm"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "282,976,34,25",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "282,976,34,25",
              "text": "14"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "281,1034,223,33",
          "words": [
            {
              "boundingBox": "281,1034,103,33",
              "text": "Library"
            },
            {
              "boundingBox": "395,1034,109,26",
              "text": "Closed"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}`

I want to be able to group all the lowest level words by date, for instance

7: Library Open 1 -5 pm,
   New Year Open House Start The New Year Right @ the Library 1-5 pm
14: Library Closed

Is there any good algorithms to do something like this, or is brute force (checking each text for a date and getting spans in the array in between) the only approach? I can put the sample image up somewhere if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well i think you're overlooking this problem. We can't sort without using number as base. So whatever the algorithm is you're still have to take the "date" out and use it as sorting base.

So at first creating a dictionary as follow

```
{
    "text1": date1,
    "text2": date2,
 }
```

Then sort it. And you're done

Comment: Sorry but I am not following. The node thst represents a date are at the same level of the text. How can I help them in this case? I feel like I am missing something.

Comment: How about using lamba to sort       unsorted_list.sort(key=lambda x: x["words"]["date"])   .

Comment: I really do not understand how to differentiate text that represents a date and one that represents an event. They are at the same level. The only way to tell is to check to see if text is a number but that isn't guaranteed to make it a date. Maybe some sample code will make it clear for me.

Comment: By event you mean  "text": "Closed". By date you mean "text": "pm" or "text": "14" ???

Comment: The example in the image I would want it to be "date": "14", "text": "Library Closed". As you can see those are 3 nodes at the same level but represent a date and one event.

Comment: OK, i understand what you want to do know. From the calendar you take part of image (for example Sunday 7th). Then upload it and have a lot of response like your post. You do not understand how to use that result to form something like "Library Open": "1 - 5 pm", .... Is that correct ?

Comment: Correct I am not sure the best approach to group the events by dates when everything is at the same depth.

Comment: Using the raw output of OCR to group the events by dates is impossible. OCR first detect text-contain regions then split each region into chunks of text. That why everything is at the same depth. First, You have to group the chunk of text to form a full sentence. Then split that sentence into "event": "time".